# How to add a favicon to a Google appengine app

Tags: java, google-app-engine

I am trying to add a favicont to a appengine web app but not completely sure how to go about it.

What i've done:

I added the following to the  of my appengine-web.xml file

 tag:    The favicon is located in src/main/webapp...
It still doesn't get served.  Any idea what i;m doing wrong?  I also added /

Answer (score 2):

Put your favicon image inside the `war` directory of project . It works for me . Nothing else needed . Path should be like this `/YourProjectName/war/favicon.ico`. You can verify this path by right clicking on properties for your favicon image .

Comment: I don't have a war directory?

Answer (score 0):

The syntax that you used is the one for the `app.yaml` file (which is used by the environments **other than** Java)

For the Java environment the static files are specified in the `appengine-web.xml` file. Look for the `<public-root>` and the `<static-files>` tags in the [appengine-web.xml Reference](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/config/appref):

> < public-root >
>
> Optional. The  is a directory in your application that
>   contains the static files for your application. When a request for a
>   static file is made, the  for your application is
>   prepended to the request path. This gives the path of an application
>   file containing the content that is being requested.
>
> The default  is /.
>
> For example, the following would map the URL path /index.html to the
>   application file path /static/index.html:
>
> ```
> <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
> <appengine-web-app xmlns="http://appengine.google.com/ns/1.0">
>   <!-- ... -->
>   <public-root>/static</public-root>
>   <!-- ... -->
> </appengine-web-app>
> ```

and

> < static-files >
>
> Optional. The  element specifies patterns that match
>   file paths to include and exclude from the list of static files,
>   overriding or amending the default behavior. Static file are served
>   from dedicated servers and caches that are separate from the
>   application servers and are useful for serving static content such as
>   images, CSS stylesheets or JavaScript files.

Comment: I tried adding it in the <static files like this as well: Dan Cornilescu  but keep getting a build error when I do it that way...  What am I missing/

Comment: Also I don't have a <public-root> tag in my xml file

Comment: Read the doc again. You **need** a `<public-root>` section , the `<static-files>` one just further amends it.

Comment: I have the following in my <static files> tag:  <include path="/**.ico" expiration="1d" />  The favicon is located in src/main/webapp...
It still doesn't get served.  Any idea what i'm doing wrong?  I also added <public-root>/</public-root>

Comment: Please edit your question with your updated info - code in comments is unreadable.